# Why does XSLT add newline (carriage return) in IE10

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, xslt

This just started with IE10 as far as I can tell.

It's not an issue in FF.

Using XMLHttpRequest to get some xml data, then display it using xslt...

The xslt transformation is automatically adding new lines in seemingly random locations where there is a space in an elements data.

If I preview the data using getElementsByTagName, the data is intact, no spaces have been converted to a newlines.

Since html treats new lines as a space, you can not see the issue if you simply display the text or place it in an input box, BUT, if the data is stored in a hidden element and you show it using the alert function you can see that there is a newline/carriage return in the output data.

The issue seems to be worse if there are NOT carriage returns after the elements in the original xml data. I've actually been able to get around this issue in some cases by adding a carriage return after each element. Some cases, not all.

It's almost as if when the transformer is trying to read the data it splits the data at spaces for readability and it automatically adds a carriage return.

Example:

## **xsltTest.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>xslt test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        function loadFile(f) {
            xhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest
            xhttp.open("GET", f, false)
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
            xhttp.send("")

            //in IE10 this seems to show where the new lines get added
            alert(xhttp.responseText)

            var xml = xhttp.responseXML

            displayData(xml, 'xsltTest.xslt', 'DataDiv')

        }

        function displayData(xmlResp, xslFile, targetObj) {

            var xml = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DomDocument");
            xml.async = false;
            xml.load(xmlResp);

            var xsl = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.FreeThreadedDomDocument");
            xsl.async = false;
            xsl.load(xslFile);

            xsl_template = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate")
            xsl_template.stylesheet = xsl;

            xslProc = xsl_template.createProcessor()
            xslProc.input = xml

            xslProc.transform()
            document.getElementById(targetObj).innerHTML = xslProc.output
        }

        function popData(idx,e) {
            alert(document.getElementById('data_'+idx+'_'+e).value)
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<input type="button" id="WithCRButton" value="Load File WITH CarriageReturns" onclick="loadFile('DataWithCR.xml')" />
<input type="button" id="WithoutCRButton" value="Load File WITHOUT CarriageReturns" onclick="loadFile('DataWithoutCR.xml')" />
<div style="border:1px solid black;width:100%" id="DataDiv">
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

## **xsltTest.xslt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">


    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <xsl:for-each select="TestData/field">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="elementData1"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden">
                            <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="elementData1"/></xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="id">data_<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>_1</xsl:attribute>
                        </input>
                        <input type="button" value="show hidden value">
                            <xsl:attribute name="onclick">popData('<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>','1')</xsl:attribute>
                        </input>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="elementData2"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden">
                            <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="elementData2"/></xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="id">data_<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>_2</xsl:attribute>
                        </input>
                        <input type="button" value="show hidden value">
                            <xsl:attribute name="onclick">popData('<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>','2')</xsl:attribute>
                        </input>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## **DataWithCR.xml**

```
<TestData>
<field>
<elementData1>ThisHasNoSpaces</elementData1>
<elementData2>ThisHasA Space</elementData2>
</field>
<field>
<elementData1>ThisHasNoSpaces</elementData1>
<elementData2>ThisHasA Space</elementData2>
</field>
<field>
<elementData1>ThisHasNoSpaces</elementData1>
<elementData2>ThisHasA Space</elementData2>
</field>
<field>
<elementData1>ThisHasNoSpaces</elementData1>
<elementData2>ThisHasA Space</elementData2>
</field>
</TestData>
```

## **DataWithoutCR.xml**

```
<TestData><field><elementData1>ThisHasNoSpaces</elementData1><elementData2>ThisHasA Space</elementData2></field><field><elementData1>ThisHasNoSpaces</elementData1><elementData2>ThisHasA Space</elementData2></field><field><elementData1>ThisHasNoSpaces</elementData1><elementData2>ThisHasA Space</elementData2></field><field><elementData1>ThisHasNoSpaces</elementData1><elementData2>ThisHasA Space</elementData2></field></TestData>
```

Comment: Does it help to add `<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>` in your stylesheet before the `<xsl:template match="/">`?

Comment: Can you put in what the output actually is, and what it should be?

Comment: The output is difficult to include, but what happens is, when the alert box displays the data "ThisHasA Space" there is a carriage return between the "A" and "Space" that is not in the original data.

Comment: @FrankPl, no, adding "<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>" does not help.

Comment: This may not be relevant to you (you didn't mention Chrome in the question), but I thought you might like to know that the Chrome developers are considering dropping support for XSLT in future versions on the grounds that no-one uses it any more, because it's difficult to work with and because support is poor in all browsers. If you are going to need XSLT support going forward, you should consider joining their mailing list and getting your opinion heard.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I use "ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")" instead of "window.XMLHttpRequest" the issue goes away.

It seems that Microsoft just implemented the browser-native "window.XMLHttpRequest" ... but it has bugs AND limitations.

For example, "ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")" has the transformNode method, but "window.XMLHttpRequest" does not.

For browser compatibility in my javascript code I was creating the object as follows:

```
var XMLDoc = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? (new XMLHttpRequest()) : (new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"))
```

...so in IE, as long as window.XMLHttpRequest did not exist it was using the ActiveXObject. But now that it does exist it's using it, along with all it's bugs and limitations.

I am now in the process of reversing that conditional statement everywhere its called to default to the ActiveXObject if it's available...

```
var XMLDoc = (window.ActiveXObject) ? (new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")) : (new XMLHttpRequest())
```

Comment: The absence of a `transform` method is not a limitation, this method is not even in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) to begin with. Microsoft implemented the `XMLHttpRequest` API according to that spec. This is one of the reasons why XSLT is meant to be run on the server. Don't do client side XSLT.

Comment: There are definitely situations where client side is preferable. Such as when large amounts of data have been downloaded and you simply want to resort or rearrange the data for the user. So even if we forget about transformNode and just stick to the original issue of carriage returns being introduced into the data. This is completely unacceptable. Yet another MS/IE blunder. Scroood again.

Comment: I've worked with MSXML (the library in the background) extensively and I've never seen whitespace nodes (that's what newlines are) inserted in the code **unless** `<xsl:output indent="yes" />` is set or they were already present in the input. I'm pretty sure that the error is on your end, either due to incorrect implementation or wrong expectations. In any case I'll set up a test case with the sample code you gave above and tell you my findings.

Comment: Ok, here is what I found: You were right, I was wrong. Whitespace nodes *are* inserted in the document. Key to this behavior is the [`preserveWhiteSpace` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms761353(v=vs.85).aspx), which defaults to `false`. You can set it with `xhttp.responseXML.preserveWhiteSpace = true;` right before you `send()` the request. **However**, the output your XSLT code generates should be (and is!) the same regardless of this setting, because it only affects *insignificant* whitespace, stuff that you should never care about or use anyway.

Comment: So what I don't understand is - other than that the `responseXML.xml` property does not exactly look like the input document - what exactly is the problem you have with this behavior?

Comment: Run the above example code in IE10 and you will see that when you click on the buttons, the alert box shows that a carriage return has been added into the value of the hidden fields. If I send that data in a subsequent request or even if I just compare it to the data on the page it does not match the actual data... which can cause countless issues.

Comment: It did not add any newlines when I tested it with your code. The alert boxes were absolutely equal for both inputs. MSXML *definitely* will not add anything to non-empty text nodes, only insignificant whitespace (the the sense of the formal definition of that term) is added. Are you sure your real code resembles your sample? I will try some more tomorrow when I'm back at my desk.

Comment: I've double-checked. Both XML variants (CRs or not) do behave absolutely the same, independent of whether MSXML "pretty-prints" the input XML or not. I can't see what you are griping about.

Comment: Please make sure you are using IE10 and NOT in compatibility mode. I have seen others who have referenced this problem and I can reproduce it consistently.

Comment: I'm using IE 10. I'll double check all settings tomorrow. Would you please set up a jsFiddle that exposes the behavior for you? This is to make absolutely sure we're using the same set-up.