# Internet Explorer adding line feeds with XSL processor

Tags: javascript, html, xml, internet-explorer, xslt

just as some background I have an application that in part takes an XML fragment and processes this with an XSL template to give me an HTML output.

In order to get this to work in IE, I have added this block of code:

```
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
        if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
            var xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate");
            var zxsl_activex = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument");
            zxsl_activex.async = false;
            zxsl_activex.load("/ZymonicBlockCombined.xsl");
            xslt.stylesheet = zxsl_activex;
            var xsl_proc = xslt.createProcessor();
            if ( xml instanceof Document ) { xsl_proc.input = xml; }
            else { xsl_proc.input = xml.ownerDocument; }
            xsl_proc.transform();
            return document.createRange().createContextualFragment(xsl_proc.output);
```

Which was courtesy of this post:
[Object doesn't support property or method 'transformNode' in Internet Explorer 10 (Windows 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149410/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-transformnode-in-internet-explorer-1)

The issue I have with this is that the string which is converted to a fragment (xsl_proc.output) has random line feeds in it, which must be added somewhere during that transform() function. For example, when you view the string in the console, it looks like this:

alidationResults.push(basic_validation("1453_dept_id","Area

2-Digit ID","char","",2,["[[display_name]]

The implication of this of course is that when the browser attempts to insert this fragment into the page and run the script, you get an 'Unterminated string constant' error.

The question is - is there a way to prevent the transform() function adding extra line feeds?

I'd like to point out that the input xml object does NOT have these additional line feeds, and the output from the FireFox XSLTProcessor doesn't either.

I've also tried stripping out line feeds from the string (that's pretty straightforward) but of course there's no way to determine if the linefeed was in the 'original' xml, or if it was one of the additional ones, so that won't work either.

EDIT:

The full 'transformation' method is as follows:

```
   function TransformXML(xml) {

var xsl = window.zxsl;
// FireFox, Safari, Chrome, Opera etc.
if (typeof (XSLTProcessor) != "undefined") { 
    var xslt_processor = new XSLTProcessor();
    xslt_processor.importStylesheet(xsl);
    return xslt_processor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
}

// IE8 and below
if (typeof (xml.transformNode) != "undefined") { 
    return xml.transformNode(xsl);
}

// IE9 onwards
else {
    try { 
        // This checks for all versions of IE up to 11, may need to change in future
        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
        if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
            var xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate");
            var zxsl_activex = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument");
            zxsl_activex.async = false;
            zxsl_activex.load("/ZymonicBlockCombined.xsl");
            xslt.stylesheet = zxsl_activex;
            var xsl_proc = xslt.createProcessor();
            if ( xml instanceof Document ) { xsl_proc.input = xml; }
            else { xsl_proc.input = xml.ownerDocument; }
            xsl_proc.transform();
            return document.createRange().createContextualFragment(xsl_proc.output);
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert("The type [XSLTProcessor] and the function [XmlDocument.transformNode] are not supported by this browser, can't transform XML document to HTML string!");
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Not particularly helpful I know, I tried to set up a jsFiddle for it but unfortunately it doesn't support ActiveXObjects so I don't know how else to provide more info.

The XML is just a generic fragment:

```
<report expanded="true" group_ident="ebex_performance_filter_zztlg" has_headers="true" ident="277_ebex_performance_filter_zztlg" block_id="277" blockid="277" filter_ident="277_ebex_performance_filter_">
<result ident="277_ebex_performance_filter_zztlg_0_result">
<report expanded="false" group_ident="277_ebex_performance_filter_epf_all_g" ident="277_ebex_performance_filter_zztlg_0_result_epf_all_g" result_count="0">
<navigation current_page="1" first_page="1" last_page="1" next_page="1" previous_page="1" results_per_page="1">
<error>Maximum number of results allowed is 1.</error>
</navigation>
</report>
<zz_top_level_group_field DisplayOnly="true" DisplayOrder="1" LinkField="true" ReportMode="true" ident="277_ebex_performance_filter_zztlg_0_result_field" type="Field">
<DisplayName>All</DisplayName>
</zz_top_level_group_field>
</result>
</report>
```

Likewise, any xsl file/ fragment would recreate it (since the issue is with xsl_proc.transform()).

Comment: Consider to add a minimal but complete code snippet allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: There are some people here who are brilliant at finding bugs in code that they can't see, but I'm not one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may be visiting this page in the future, I eventually solved the problem myself.
Figured out from this post that you need to set the 'preserveWhiteSpace' property on the xml to true before transforming.
[Why does XSLT add newline (carriage return) in IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087607/why-does-xslt-add-newline-carriage-return-in-ie10)

In order to do this I found that you need an ActiveXObject, so I created one and loaded my XML into it:

```
var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
xmlDoc.async = false;
var xmlFragment = ((xml instanceof Document) ? xml : xml.ownerDocument);
xmlDoc.loadXML(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlFragment));
```

Note that my incoming xml is either a Document or an Object (hence the ternary condition), and I then serialized this to a string to be loaded into the xml axtivexobject.

The code now looks like this (and does what I need it to do):

```
        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
        if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
            var xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate");
            var zxsl_activex = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument");
            zxsl_activex.async = false;
            zxsl_activex.load("/ZymonicBlockCombined.xsl");
            xslt.stylesheet = zxsl_activex;
            var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
            xmlDoc.async = false;
            xmlDoc.preserveWhiteSpace = true;
            var xmlFragment = ((xml instanceof Document) ? xml : xml.ownerDocument);
            xmlDoc.loadXML(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlFragment));
            var xsl_proc = xslt.createProcessor();
            xsl_proc.input = xmlDoc;
            xsl_proc.transform();
            return document.createRange().createContextualFragment(xsl_proc.output);
        }
```